# Cannot use aggregation operations in $set inside updateMany

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB (4.4.8) collection where I want to change the value of some field based on its previous value. For example, I want to convert all strings to uppercase.

For this, I use the following query:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    { field: { $regex: "[a-z]+"}},
    { $set: { field: { $toUpper: "$field" } } }
)
```

when executing the query, it gives me the following error:

> MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$toUpper' in 'field.$toUpper' is not valid for storage

The same occurs if I use similar operations such as `$concat` (with an array parameter) to append something to the field.

When I look up similar questions, it all uses `update` and tells me to use `updateMany` instead, or it says that it only works in mongoDB >= 4.2. However, I have both of these things.

If I am correct, you are able to use aggregation syntax (among which `$toUpper`) in conjunction with `$set` inside updateMany queries for these newer versions of mongoDB.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If I've undesrtood correctly, aggregation stage into `update` one is using `[ ]`, like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tkDl1cCLr3j)

Comment: The `$toUpper` operator is a aggregation operator, and you have used in regular update query, you try update with aggregation pipeline, just wrap your update part in array bracket [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments of J.F. and turivishal, I managed to solve this by changing it into the following:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    { field: { $regex: "[a-z]+"}},
    [ { $set: { field: { $toUpper: "$field" } } } ]
)
```